# Make a new array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs, daterangepicker

Need help to make new array, when I have two array

First one:

```
var start=[ "11/10/2021", "05/10/2021", "16/10/2021", "03/10/2021" ]
```

The second:

```
var end=[ "10/10/2021", "04/10/2021", "15/10/2021", "01/10/2021" ]
```

And I make a new array with code, but get an error:

```
var start= [];
var end= [];
var daterange =[];
var daterange = JSON.stringify(response);
var textdiv=JSON.parse(daterange );
for (var i = 0; i < textdiv.length; i++) {
     sart.push(textdiv[i].a);
     end.push(textdiv[i].b);
     daterange.push('start'=>moment(textdiv[i].a),'end'=>moment(textdiv[i].b));
}
```

So the output is as follows:

```
var daterange =[{
    'start': moment('2021-10-10'),
    'end': moment('2021-10-15')
  },
  {
    'start': moment('2021-10-25'),
    'end': moment('2021-10-30')
  }
];
```

Comment: _"but error"_. It helps if you share the error, but I can guess it's because you have `var daterange` twice. Once the variable is defined/set, you can't run `var` on it again. Btw, why are you first running `JSON.stringify()` just to do `JSON.parse()` on the result in the line below? Why not just use `response` directly?

Comment: How does your response data look?

Comment: Also, in your loop, `daterange` will be a string (result of `JSON.stringify()`) which means that you can't `.push()` things to it.

Comment: And `sart.push` is probably `start.push`

Comment: I'm no JS expert, but this: `.push('start'=>moment(textdiv[i].a),'end'=>moment(textdiv[i].b))` looks a bit odd.

Comment: @MagnusErikssonis it like this right `daterange.push('start':moment(response[i].a),'end':moment(response[i].b));`

Comment: You need to define it as an object (wrapping it in `{ }`). `push({'start': moment(...), 'end': moment(...)})`.

Answer (score -2):

I took whatever is coming in textdiv and store it in proper key,value pair as required in daterange array via creating an object. Moment only converts string to date in given format.

```
    var start= []; // if you already have start, you can not reinitialize it, I think you are creating a fresh array here for later use.
    var end= [];
    var daterange =[];
    var daterange = JSON.stringify(response);
    var textdiv=JSON.parse(daterange );
console.log(textdiv, daterange); // please check what you are actually getting after parsing to understand your error better
    for (var i = 0; i < textdiv.length; i++) {
         let a = textdiv[i].a; // there is a typo here
         let b = textdiv[i].b;
         daterange.push({'start' :moment(a).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),'end':moment(b).format('YYYY-MM-DD')});// you need to store them as object if you want to push them together and use format function to properly insert it as date.
    }
```

Comment: also please post your error for better resolution.

Comment: This will not work: `daterange` is an array, you set as string and try to push item in a string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).